# move instances of td content to another tr td up in DOM

Tags: jquery

I have a table where i need to move some content from one tr > td , to another tr > td up in the DOM. I have tried using .prev() and .closest() with no luck. Using append will create multiple instances of the content.

Tried this

```
$('td.move-here').append($('td.move-inner-content')).contents();
$('td.move-inner-content').prev('td.move-here');
$('td.move-inner-content').closest('td.move-here');
```

Here is example of the HTML

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr><th></th></tr>

      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content">Move this content1 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"</td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>



      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content">Move this content2 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"</td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>



      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content">Move this content3 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"</td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to move all instances of the content for td.move-inner-content , to the closest previous td cell called td.move-here , so that cell will contain it original content , plus the appended content. So the resulting HTML will be as follows.

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr><th></th></tr>

      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">
             Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content
             Move this content1 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>



      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">
             Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content
             Move this content2 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>



      <tr class="trow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="move-here">
             Oringinal Content Here ADD "move-inner-content" here keeping original content
             Move this content3 here to closest/previous "td.move-here"
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="move-inner-content"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post the jquery you tried also.

Comment: got it Daniel , thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for , any suggestions on anything better ?

```
$('tr:has("td.move-inner-content")').each(function() {
  $(this).prev().find('td.move-here').append(this); 
});

$('.move-inner-content').contents().unwrap().unwrap();
```